# Why is this not an exponential function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

$$5\times 1.2^x-3$$

Is it simply that it doesn't follow the form "$ca^x$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can't be written in that form. Notice that function of the form of $ca^x$ doesn't change sign.

But for our function $f(x)=5 \times 1.2^x-3$,

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-3$$ and $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty.$$

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't follow that $\,f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\,$, which is what makes a function eligible to be even considered as being called exponential. For why *not* all functions that obey the above are actually exponential, see 
the answers under [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

---

[ *EDIT* ]  If using a definition of exponentials which includes functions of the form $\,\color{red}{c \cdot} a^x\,$, then the equality above needs to be changed to $\,f(0)f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\,$.

Comment: But then ca^x wouldn't be an exponential function either?

(Sorry about the math, format...)

Comment: @Z.Apa *The* exponential functon is $\,e^x\,$, and functions of the form $\,e^{\lambda x} = a^x\,$ are also called exponentials pretty much everywhere. Those of the form $\,e^{\lambda x+\mu} = ca^x\,$ may or may not be called exponential functions depending on the definition you are using. I added a clarification at the end of the answer.

Comment: I hope you don't mind an exception to the rule against comments like "thanks", but your addition really made a huge difference. So thank you!

Comment: @Z.Apa Glad it helped. Also prompted me to re-read that addition and correct the "edit" vs. "exit" typo ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the $-3$ is exactly what makes your function not exponential.